# Studies on the change in effectiveness of pedagogical practices over time

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, reference-request, general-pedagogy

Are there any studies that have investigated this question?

**Why certain pedagogical practices that used to be effective up to a few years ago, may suddenly become less or even no longer effective?**

I am specifically interested in this question in the field of mathematics education, but I am also interested in such studies in a broader context.

Thank you.

Comment: It is common wisdom that any new learning method or tool gets pupil interest for a while, but you seem to be looking for a longer-term effect.

Comment: *certain pedagogical practices that used to be effective up to a few years ago* Like what?

Comment: I didn't intend to imply that there are pedagogical practices that used to be universally effective up until a few years ago and now they are not. The question is local. Think of something you used to do to engage your students and it worked very well up until recently, but now it is not as engaging anymore. You may have experienced that, or not, I don't know. I have examples from my own teaching. If this happens somewhere (locally) within only a few years, what could possibly cause it? I am asking if this question has been studied. Of course I can speculate, but that wouldn't be convincing.

Comment: "Think of something you used to do to engage your students ... but now it is not as engaging anymore." I'm an old school guy, so I'm just using stick and carrot (slightly varying both depending on the circumstances). Its efficiency doesn't seem to change. :-) The way you mean it, it seems like a question about very localized settings that can be as small as one teacher within one school. I doubt it has ever been studied at that scale, but look at the composition of the student body and the preparedness level. If it doesn't help, look in the mirror and ask if you have changed yourself somehow.

Comment: The composition of the student body hasn't changed, the preparedness level hasn't changed (where I work students have never been prepared), and I haven't changed (other than having gotten older!) Something else has changed. I think students' *culture of learning* has changed. (Culture of learning:  students' answers to: what is mathematics? what does it mean to learn mathematics? how does one learn mathematics? etc.) Therefore, the possible study that I am looking for would be probably looking into the connection between effectiveness of pedagogy and students' culture of learning.

Comment: You do not need any official study here: just recall how you learned your favorite subjects and your least favorite ones and think of whether there could be anything that would change your attitudes towards the latter. Maybe the answer is "nothing". Then you can either ignore the issue or try to change the course material (Warning: artificial "real life" nonsense like bank investments at 6%, patients whose temperature is $95+2t^2$ (in Fahrenheit) on day $t$, etc. cause nothing but nausea; also do not sacrifice rigor when making subjects "sexier". If you want a better advice, give more details.

Comment: I am not looking for an official study to tell me what is happening or what to do. That, I know myself. But if we want to explain the situation to someone else, we need to back what we claim to be the culprit, using some sort of evidence, preferably in the form of a study. So this question is for the purpose of using such a study as citation. Of course, even citing studies may not convince some people, but that's their own problem.

Comment: My experience is that you can convince someone of something only in two situations: 1) You have common experience and common criteria for truth and 2) You have a machine-gun and the other person doesn't. But yeah, now it is at least clear what you are after, so I hope someone will be able to give you a satisfactory answer. :-)

As to "I know myself what to do", I usually just do it in such situations without explaining anything to anybody. If it works, nobody asks for any justification later. If it doesn't, I stop doing it anyway and accept both the failure and the scolding :-)

Comment: I completely agree with (1) and (specially) (2)!